# How can I remove values from output statement given a condition? - c++

Tags: c++, arrays, validation

I'm a little confused as to how to go around this. I have some array variables with some information, and I want to print them out after some calculations. If the value is 0, then I want to print a " " instead. There are 3 arrays that need to get checked however, how would I change the output statement to cater for all 3 checks and print an empty string instead of the value?

```
for(int start = 1; start < 13; start++)
    {

        if(check[start] == 1)
        {

            cout << checkMonth(start) << ": " << setprecision(1) << fixed << averagespeed[start] << "(" << setprecision(1) << fixed << sdSpeed[start] << ")," << setprecision(1) << fixed << averagetemp[start] << "(" << setprecision(1) << fixed << sdTemp[start] << ")," << setprecision(1) << fixed << Solar[start] << '\n';

        }
        /*if(sumTemp[start] == 0 || sumTemp[start] == 0 || sumSpeed[start] == 0){



        }*/
    }
```

Example Output looks like this:

```
January,5.5(1.2),25.5(12.2),196.4
```

For example if Sum of Speed is 0, that means all values of speed were 0 or null. So it should change to this:

```
January,,25.5(12.2),196.4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single line to `std::cout` doesn't need to be done in one statement. For example:

```
std::cout << "First";
std::cout << ", second"
std::cout << ", third\n"
```

Prints the following line:
`First, second, third`

Now we can use an `if` to conditionally print the middle part of the string:

```
std::cout << a;
if (b != 0) {
    std::cout << ", " << b;
}
std::cout << ", " << c << '\n';
```